# Python dedicated class for file names

Tags: python, file, class, variables

I am writing a program that utilises a large number of files. Does Python feature an inbuilt class for file paths, or does one have to be implemented by the user (like below):

```
class FilePath:
    def __init__(path):
        shazam(path)

    def shazam(self, path):
        """ something happens, path is formatted, etc """
        self.formatted_path = foobar
```

**Why would it be useful?**

Suppose the program and its data is copied to a different operating system. The class could modify itself on launch to support the a different path separator.

**Why not just write it yourself?**

Someone might have already written a class in the standard Python library.

Comment: Is this homework? You should specify that it is in your question.

Comment: @Soviut No, this is not homework.

Comment: Cannot we make use of os.path.abspath or os.name to differentiate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python has several cross platform modules for dealing with the file system, [paths](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) and [operating system](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html).

The [`os`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) module specifically has an [`os.sep`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.sep) character.

[`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) is OS-aware and will use the correct separator when joining paths together.

Additionally, [`os.path.normpath()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath) will take any path and convert the separators to whatever the native OS supports.

Answer (score 1):

Since Python 3.4 there is [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) which seems to be what you are looking for. Of course there are the functions from [os.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html), too - but for an object-oriented approach pathlib is fitting better.